# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data' in displaying linked list

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list

I'm trying to display linked list elements in the form of a list but keep getting this error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data=None,next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
   
    def insert_at_beginning(self,data):
        node = Node(data,self.head)
        self.head = node
        
    def display(self):
        elements = []
        currNode = self.head
        while currNode:
            currNode = currNode.next
            elements.append(currNode.data)
        print(elements)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ll = LinkedList()
    ll.insert_at_beginning(1)
    ll.insert_at_beginning(2)
    ll.insert_at_beginning(3)
    ll.display()
```

Can anyone explain the error here?

Comment: The error is that some variable is `None` but you expected it to be a `Node`.

Comment: yes i figured that but cannot find which one

Comment: The error message should tell you that. I guess it's `currNode.next`.

Answer (score 2):

After the while loop, `append` data first then go to the next. You're getting the error because if `currNode.next` is null then it's showing the object has no attribute `'data'`. So, append first then go to next. If `currNode.next` is null then the loop will stop.

```
while currNode:
    elements.append(currNode.data)
    currNode = currNode.next
```